# Can any one tell me in which jar file I can find the de.enough.polish.ui.Command?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, j2mepolish

Hi Everyone I am working on J2ME polish project, which is just an enhancement project. I have no idea about J2ME Polish. I have an error saying that the 
import de.enough.polish.ui.Command cannot be resolved. So can any one tell me where can I find that. I have tried googling but could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download [j2meploish](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/download/download/) once downloaded and installed you should look in the $installdirectory/source/j2mepolish-client.jar or something with the word client in.

Comment: I do have the client.jar in the library, even denit gives me the error

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this [website](http://devices.enough.de/interactivedb/welcome.faces), they probably have the library you are looking for.